# Does Touch ID work differently between Apple Pay and iPhone unlock?

Tags: iphone, touch-id

I'm only asking this out of curiosity. I've noticed that when I use my Touch ID to pay with iPhone, or to unlock an app, it's much quicker and it always works. However, while unlocking the iPhone, sometimes I need to put my thumb 2 or 3 times till  it unlocks. I noticed this happening with different iPhone models too.

Is there any explanation for this? May I just be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No. You may experience slower response times due to presence of moisture or dust on or under Touch ID sensor or finger/thumb respectively.

Cleaning/Drying the Touch ID sensor/finger usually resolves the lag issue.

iPhone 6s and later (excluding iPhone SE and all Touch ID equipped models of iPad) have a *second generation* Touch ID sensor which is much faster at recognizing finger/thumb geometry.

Comment: You're right.  I know that.  Didn't you notice this then, I mean what I described?  Thank you.

Comment: @Antonio23249 I have noticed it too, but not exclusively with unlocking. I experienced it when there was moisture/dust on the sensor/under finger and cleaning/drying instantaneously resolved the lag.

Comment: when my fingers are a bit wet or cold I usually opt to use the passcode.  Which makes me think passcode oglers may choose rainy days in a bus stop to learn passcodes....(just a joke)